# Execute multiple functions with parameters to be fired in order on ajax sucess

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm attempting to write a couple of functions using jQuery to help me test some api endpoints that I'm writing in php. I'm a novice when it comes to Javascript and jQuery and I'm having difficulty working out what I need to read up on in order to get things working that way I need it.

**Here are the requirements I'm attempting to meet:**

- Call should be non blocking
- Functions only to be fired on `success` and in order
- I need to pass parameters along with the functions rather than just function names
- Each function needs to be able to access the `data` variable return by `success: function(data)` from within the `api()` function

I've read the jQuery docs and believe that `deferred` and `promises` are possibly the avenue I should be pursuing but I am not able to get an example working.

**Simplified versions of my two functions:**

(For clarity)

```
// Returns data from an api request providing something hasn't gone horribly wrong
function api( api, method, endpoint, query ) {
    $.ajax({
        type: method,
        url: '/api/' + api + '/' + endpoint,
        data: query,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {

            // I currently have a single hardcoded function
            populate( data.result, '#resource', null );

        },
        error: function( data ) {
            // Debug
            dump(data.result);
        }
    });

    // Do some other stuff here
}

// Example call
$('body').on('click', '#bigFatButton', function() {

    // I would like to specify a function (or chain of functions)
    // to be fired on success along with the api() function

    api('resources', 'get', 'document', {
        debug: '1',
        id: '7'
    })

});
```

**This is what I'd like to achieve (something nice, short and reusable):**

`fn1()` and `fn2()` are fired in order and can both access the data returned by `api()`

```
api('resources', 'get', 'document', {
    debug: '1',
    id: '7'
}).fn1(data, 'custom', 'params').fn2(data, {other: 'params'}).alert('wooty!');
```

What would be the best way of achieving something similar to this? A nudge in the right direction would be very much appreciated!

Thank you.

Comment: The requested way is not possible. You can't chain a asynchronous request via the function api. The data would not yet be available when `fn1` is fired.

Comment: Do fn1 and fn2 do any kind of async operations?

Comment: @Mouser you can't say that! Sure, they need to be able to access the data from `api`. But that doesn't mean fn1 or fn2 is async.

Comment: @Ishettyl Sorry I've misunderstood it. You have a valid point asking your question!

Comment: @Mouser right I realise that the data wouldn't be available yet and was hoping there was a way deferring the execution of a function until it was.

Comment: @lshettyl strictly speaking `fn1()` and `fn2()` aren't async, but there's a good chance I'll introduce something that is and wanted to design for it ahead of time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding `return` statement before `$.ajax()` , returning `data` from `api` , utilizing `.then()`

```
function api( api, method, endpoint, query ) {
    // return `$.ajax()` jQuery promise to `.then()`
    return $.ajax({
        type: method,
        url: '/api/' + api + '/' + endpoint,
        data: query,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {

            // I currently have a single hardcoded function
            populate( data.result, '#resource', null );
            // return `data`
            return data

        },
        error: function( data ) {
            // Debug
            dump(data.result);
        }
    });

    // Do some other stuff here
}

// Example call
$('body').on('click', '#bigFatButton', function() {

    // I would like to specify a function (or chain of functions)
    // to be fired on success along with the api() function

    api('resources', 'get', 'document', {
        debug: '1',
        id: '7'
    }).then(function(data) {
         $.when(fn1(data, 'custom', 'params')
               , fn2(data, {other: 'params'})
         .then(function() {alert('wooty!')})
    })

});
```

Comment: This was where I started off after reading the jQuery docs. In my tests nothing is fired at all. When I tried your example I had the same issue.

Comment: @Matt _"In my tests nothing is fired at all. When I tried your example I had the same issue. "_ See updated post. Added `return` statement before `$.ajax()` to return jQuery promise to `.then()`

Comment: Adding the `return` statement before `$.ajax()` fixed it. Your solution works perfectly. Thanks for taking the time to help me get this working.

Answer (score 0):

1 - I would use the methods as arguments in an anonymous function

```
api('resources', 'get', 'document', {
    debug : true, // better to say true or false :)
    id : 7, // if your id is a number use number
    callback : function(data){
        fn1(data);
        fn2(data);
    }
});
```

2 - Using an array, could be cool if you have a lot to run.

```
// in api method..
for(var i; i < cbks.lengths; i++){
    cbks[i](); // execute one by one the callbacks declared.
}

api('resources', 'get', 'document', {
    debug : true, // better to say true or false :)
    id : 7, // if your id is a number use number
    [fn1, fn2, fn3] // here are the callbacks
});
```

Comment: I can't test if this works due to `SyntaxError: Unexpected token '('. Expected a ':' following the property name 'function'.` I'm a novice when it comes to Javascript and can't tell where the typo is.

Comment: forgot to add the key before the value of the first example :) should be better !

Answer (score 0):

Due to the asynchronous nature of AJAX you can't chain functions directly from the API function. The data would simply not be available when the chained functions are ran. However you can do it inside the success function. You will need to construct a wrapper function.

```
function wrapper()
{
    return {
       fn1 : function(data){
           //execute code for fn1 here
           return wrapper();
       },
       fn2 : function(data){
           //execute code for fn2 here
           return wrapper();
       },
       alert : window.alert.bind(window);
       }
    }
}
```

By running `wrapper.fn1(data, arguments).fn2(data, arguments).alert("whoot!")` inside the success function it will work the way you intended.

Everytime you call upon the `wrapper` function, or a function inside it it will return the full object allowing for function chaining.

A more efficient design would be to construct the functions outside the wrapper object and only reference them inside the wrapper function.

Comment: How would I pass this to the api() function? I don't want anything hardcoded inside the function. There are dozens of endpoints with hundreds of combinations of parameters to test with the data returned from the api() function and I need to keep things as modular and reusable as possible. Apologies if I've miss understood.